# Uncountable product of many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not paracompact

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be the product of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $(X,\tau)$ is not paracompact.

In order to prove that something is not paracompact. We need to find an open cover that does not have an open locally finite refinement. How would this open cover look like in uncountable product of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Paracompact Hausdorff spaces are normal. $X$ is a classic example of a non-normal space.

Answer (score 2):

To find facts about spaces, you can try looking it up at

[Pi Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000101)

In this case, it says your space is T_2 and not normal, but paracompact+T_2 implies normal, so it is not paracompact.

Comment: In particular look [here](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces/S000101)